# Real-world example where std::atomic::compare_exchange used with two memory_order parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Can you give a real-world example where two memory_order parameter version of `std::atomic::compare_exchange` is used for a reason (so the one memory_order parameter version is not adequate)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many cases, the second memory orderering parameter on `compare_exchange` is set to `memory_order_relaxed`. In those cases, it is usually not wrong to omit it, just potentially less efficient.

Here is an example of a simple, lock-free, list/stack that requires a second, different, ordering parameter on `compare_exchange_weak` in order to be data-race-free.

Calls to `push` can be executed concurrently, but to avoid the complexities of lock-free data manipulation,
the assumption is made that nodes cannot be removed from the stack while calls to `push` are executed; i.e. to avoid dangling pointers.

```
template<typename T>
class mystack {

    struct node {
        node *next = nullptr;

        T data;
        int id;

        node(int id) : id{id} { }
    };

    std::atomic<node *> head{nullptr};

public:
    void push(T data, int id);
    bool pop(T &data); // not implemented
};


template<typename T>
void mystack<T>::push(T data, int id)
{
    node *newnode = new node{id};

    newnode->data = std::move(data);

    node *current_head = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);   // A

    for (;;)
    {
        newnode->next = current_head;

        if (head.compare_exchange_weak(current_head, newnode,
                                       std::memory_order_release,   // B
                                       std::memory_order_acquire))  // C
        {
            /*
             * 'current_head' may not be derefenced here since the initial load (at A)
             * does not order memory 'current_head' is pointing at.
             *
             * a release barrier (at B) is necessary to make 'newnode' available
             * to other threads
             */
            std::cout << "Insertion successful\n";

            break;

        } else
        {
            /*
             * 'current_head' is the updated head pointer after 'compare_exchange' failed
             * Since it was inserted by another thread (the CAS failed),
             * an acquire barrier must be set (at C) in order to be able to access data
             * 'current_head' is pointing at.
             */
            std::cout << "Insertion failed after head changed to id: " <<
                          current_head->id << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

In `push`, the initial `load` (at A) is a relaxed operation, meaning that even though the `head` pointer is loaded atomically,
it may not be dereferenced since the memory it refers to is unordered in this thread.

In case `compare_exchange_weak` returns success, `newnode` is inserted at the head of the list and made available to other threads by setting a release barrier (at B).
Another thread that accesses this data (later, via `pop`) needs to set an acquire barrier.

In case `compare_exchange_weak` returns failure (forget spuriously), another thread just inserted a new `node` instance and `current_head` is updated with the new value of `head`.
Since `current_head` is now pointing at data that was allocated and released in another thread, an acquire barrier is necessary if `current_head` is going to be dereferenced.
This is true since the `cout` failure message includes `current_head->id`.

Had the last parameter been omitted, the first barrier parameter would have been used for the failure `load` scenario, but since this is a release barrier, 
the effective barrier would have decayed to `memory_order_relaxed`, causing a data race on `current_head->id`.

Comment: Thanks for the very good answer! Just a question: could you use consume order for failure in the example? I think the answer is yes, because current_head->id is a dependent read.

Comment: @geza  Thank you! .. Yes, in this case you could use `memory_order_consume` because  (1) the store to `current_head` is _dependency-ordered before_ the `compare_exchange` failure load of `current_head` and
(2) `current_head` carries a dependency to `current_head->id`..
It is not recommended though; C++17 deprecates the use of `memory_order_consume` because "_the semantics have been found inadequate_"

Comment: @LWimsey Compiler writers have found it too difficult to convince the intermediate pass and back end of the compiler to honor consume semantics in all cases even in degenerate dependencies. Also, there is no way for the back end to tell the front end that a dependency will be removed and that a fence may be needed.

Comment: @curiousguy yes, and I think that's why using `consume` is discouraged